APIM API Export to Open API v3 Json Format does not Deploy using Bicep
I have exported my API containing 3 operations into an Open API v3 JSON file. They use 3 schemas for request-response. If I delete my API in APIM and import from this file they are recreated correctly in APIM. However, when I come to use Bicep and YAML to deploy I see the following exception: syntax error near unexpected token `('
I have tried many things to no avail. I have another API that is imported using Bicep successfully.
The Bicep:
resource apimServiceName_apiName 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis@2023-09-01-preview' = {
  name: '${apimServiceName}/${name}'
  properties: {
    format: definitionFormat
    value: definitionContent
    path: apiPath
  }
}

YAML that calls into the Bicep above:
steps:
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: 'Add API : ${{ parameters.name }}'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureServiceConnection }}
      scriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        az deployment group create \
          --resource-group '${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }}' \
          --name 'iac.${{ parameters.apiManagementServiceName }}' \
          --template-file '../sourceArtifact/resources/apimanagement/cli/apis/APIM.AddApiFromDefinition.bicep' \
          --parameters 'apimServiceName=${{ parameters.apiManagementServiceName }}' \
          --parameters 'name=${{ parameters.name }}' \
          --parameters 'definitionFormat=${{ parameters.definitionFormat }}' \
          --parameters 'definitionContent=${{ parameters.definitionContent }}' \
          --parameters 'apiPath=${{ parameters.apiPath }}'

YAML that calls the one above:
 - task: PowerShell@2
     name: getDefinitionContent
     displayName: 'Load File Content'
     inputs:
       targetType: 'inline'
       script: |
         $content = Get-Content -Path ../sourceArtifact/resources/apimanagement/resources/apis/Internal API.openapi+json.json" -Raw
         echo $content
         Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=fileContent;isoutput=true]$content"
  
   - template: ../apimanagement/cli/apis/APIM.AddApiFromDefinition.yaml
     parameters:
       azureServiceConnection: ${{ parameters.azureServiceConnection }}
       resourceGroupName: '$(coreResourceGroupName)'
       apiManagementServiceName: '$(coreApimInstance)'
       name: 'internal-api'
       definitionFormat: 'openapi+json'
       definitionContent: '$(getDefinitionContent.fileContent)'
       apiPath: '/internal/erp'

The open api JSON file is flattened.

Please use hardcode instead of parameter for az deployment group create command in your template for a check, does it work? In addition, mutiple line variable is not supported in DevOps, please add a step to validate the variable value $(getDefinitionContent.fileContent).

Fixed it!  It might have been the decoding or the fact that I specified the YAML parameters incorrectly???
- task: PowerShell@2
    name: getHCMDefinitionContent
    displayName: 'Load File Content - Oracle HCM Internal API'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
#      script: |
#        $content = Get-Content -Path "../sourceArtifact/resources/apimanagement/resources/apis/Oracle HCM Internal API.openapi+json.json" -Raw
#        echo $content
#        Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=fileContent;isoutput=true]$content"
      script: |
              $content = Get-Content -Path "../sourceArtifact/resources/apimanagement/resources/apis/Oracle HCM Internal API.openapi+json.json" -Raw
              $encodedContent = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($content))
              Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=fileContent;isoutput=true]$encodedContent"

Then:
steps:
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: 'Add API : ${{ parameters.name }}'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureServiceConnection }}
      scriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        # Decode the definitionContent from base64
        decodedDefinitionContent=$(echo "${{ parameters.definitionContent }}" | base64 --decode)
        
        echo "Decoded Definition Content:"
        echo "$decodedDefinitionContent"
        
        # Use the decoded definition content in the az deployment command
        az deployment group create \
          --resource-group '${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }}' \
          --name 'iac.${{ parameters.apiManagementServiceName }}' \
          --template-file '../sourceArtifact/resources/apimanagement/cli/apis/APIM.AddApiFromDefinition.bicep' \
          --parameters apimServiceName='${{ parameters.apiManagementServiceName }}' \
          --parameters name='${{ parameters.name }}' \
          --parameters definitionFormat='${{ parameters.definitionFormat }}' \
          --parameters definitionContent="$decodedDefinitionContent" \
          --parameters apiPath='${{ parameters.apiPath }}'


So what was the issue ?

I base64 encoded the open api json to pass from YAML to YAML, then decoded before calling the bicep, but also this didn't look right on the az deployment command:
--parameters 'definitionContent=${{ parameters.definitionContent }}' 
So changed to:
--parameters definitionContent="$decodedDefinitionContent" \

${{ parameters.definitionContent }} is not decoded yet in template, so you need to decode and use $decodedDefinitionContent instead. Thanks for your sharing. You can consider accepting it as answer so that more members can benefit from the accepted answer.
